# How to keep frat bench from racking (photos)

Tags: wood-repair, racking

The slanted 72 inch boards are not screwed into anything, but I would like to add them to keep the bench strong side to side.

I don't want to screw into the back bottom joint as it already has 4 screws in it and any more I feel would cause cracking.

Should I move the 72 in a bit and just get extra long screws to screw though it at an angle and then into the bottom board?

How might I do this without screwing into the same areas too much? 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The type of instability you're asking about is called "racking".

Comment: You are on the right track by adding diagonal bracing.  If possible I would extend it further, preferably from one lower corner to the opposite upper corner.  If you do this one brace should be sufficient, no need for two in an "X".

Comment: Another option would be two steel cables with turnbuckles crossing from corner to corner in an "X".  Since these only provide support in tension you would need two.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 What do you mean extend it further? You mean the bottom board?

Comment: I mean that the diagonal board should go all the way from the lower left corner of the back (on the ground) to the upper right corner of the back.  Racking attempts to turn your square (rectangular) piece of furniture into a parallelogram.  If you can stop the diagonal length from changing you can prevent racking.  The more directly your bracing addresses this the more stable it will make your piece.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 That was my thought but the back corner already has 4 screws in them. Wouldn't screwing in any more lead to severe cracking?

Comment: Move the board up a few inches from the bottom, predrill holes to prevent splitting, or add in a block for all the pieces to connect to.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 Thank you! Exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: Are any of the joints glued or all just screwed? If you add glue you will increase stability quite a bit, although diagonal bracing or something else (e.g. plywood gussets) is still a must without any proper joinery joining the various pieces together.

Comment: @GraphussupportsMonica They are not glued they are simply screwed. I am going to add tension wire with turnbuckles as I can't seem to find a good place to add wood framing with out drilling too much.